# How the Integration Runtime works with S3

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-data-factory

Can anyone tell me how the IR of Azure data factory works with S3?
I know that S3 is only supported as a source not sink, then how the IR Gateway works with the S3??

Answer (score 0):

Currently, ADF doesn't support S3 as a sink. But if you have s3 odbc driver, you could try ODBC connector of ADF.